# select2 in modal search box not working like disabled

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, jquery-select2

i have a modal which has a select2 component, but its not working as it should, the search box is like disabled

[image: in my aplication search box not working]

[image: search box works on default theme]

```
<div class="modal fade" id="m_modal_1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

this my code for my modal

```
$('#m_modal_1').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
           
            $('#id_golongan').select2({
                placeholder: "Pilih Golongan"
            })
        });
```

this my JS

i have got rid of `tabindex="-1"` and used `$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};` but not working, if i used `dropdownParent: $("#modal_penguasaan")` modal disappears when i click

what can i do so that the modal doesn't disappear when i click select2 and the search box works normally